How can I mock select.select at class level?
I am trying to mock select.select for some testing I am doing that involves sockets.
Here is my setUpClass:
class ClientTestsBase(unittest.TestCase):

    socket_mock = mock.Mock() # patch('socket.socket')
    select_mock = patch('select.select')
    client = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.select_mock.return_value = [cls.socket_mock], [], []
        
        cls.client = Client(1, cls.socket_mock, '0.0.0.0:0')

        os.environ["DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS"] = '300'

Here is my test set up to work with the above setUpClass:
    #@patch('select.select')
    def test_get(self):
        # select_mock.return_value = [self.socket_mock], [], []
        self.socket_mock.recv.return_value.decode.return_value = 'y'
        response = TestGet.client.get()
        self.assertEqual(response, 'y') 

This setup leads to the following error:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([self.socket], [], [], 0)
TypeError: fileno() returned a non-integer

However, if I remove the comments from the test_get method to crete the patch on the fly, it works fine:
    @patch('select.select')
    def test_get(self, select_mock):
        select_mock.return_value = [self.socket_mock], [], []
        self.socket_mock.recv.return_value.decode.return_value = 'y'
        response = TestGet.client.get()
        self.assertEqual(response, 'y')

What you see above is pretty much all I have tried. Once I saw it worked in the test_get method, I tried to move it to the setUpClass method and it broke.
[EDIT]
I tried setting it up in the instance setUp, with no luck.
    @patch('select.select')
    def setUp(self, select_mock) -> None:
        # self.select_mock = patch('select.select')
        select_mock.return_value = [self.socket_mock], [], []


patch does not return a mock, it returns the patcher that first needs to be started (and stopped in tearDown). Using the decorator in setUp would restrict the patching to the setUp method itself, so that can't work.

Thanks. Since posting this, I've learned a little more about how to structure my tests. Turns out I was testing the wrong thing.
